# HttpSession class not found

Tags: maven, grails, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am building a project using groovy on grails 2.3.7. Rather that using the default grails plugins I want to configure the plugins as maven dependencies.

I also want to use jetty server instead of tomcat server and mongodb instead of the regular relational databases.

After creating the project I executed '**grails create-pom**' to create the pom.xml file for the project.

I have added the following changes to the pom.xml.

1. Removed the dependency for hibernate and added the following dependency for mongodb

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.1</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
       <type>zip</type>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Removed the default plugin for tomcat and added the following plugin for jetty.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
       <type>zip</type>
   </dependency>
   ```

I have also configured the repository for grails plugins.

While executing the code I get the following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycompany:grails-mongodb-demo:grails-app:0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 200, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building grails-mongodb-demo 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ grails-mongodb-demo ---
[INFO] Deleting /mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-mongodb-demo/target
[INFO] Deleting /mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-mongodb-demo/plugins (includes = [**/*], excludes = [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:clean (default-clean) @ grails-mongodb-demo ---
[WARNING] Grails Start with out fork
|Loading Grails 2.3.7
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to development
....................
|Application cleaned.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:validate (default-validate) @ grails-mongodb-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:init (default-init) @ grails-mongodb-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:config-directories (default-config-directories) @ grails-mongodb-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7:maven-compile (default-maven-compile) @ grails-mongodb-demo ---
[WARNING] Grails Start with out fork
|Loading Grails 2.3.7
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
..........
|Compiling 12 source files
.Error 
|
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSession (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Can anyone please tell me, what plugin I am missing or is there some thing I have configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you pom.xml and see if it helps:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Just had to add this on Maven Spring Project using JUint and Mockito to Mock Session and it worked, thanks.